# Java Mail: Operation timeout while sending mail over Gmail SMTP on port 587

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

Trying to write a java mail API program but getting following error:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
```

Here is the java code I have written:

```
String HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
String PORT = "587";
String USERNAME = "myname@gmail.com";
String PASSWORD = "myPassword";

Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", USERNAME);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", PASSWORD);


    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);


    // 2) compose message
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(request.getSenderEmailId()));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[request.getRecipients().size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < request.getRecipients().size(); i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(request.getRecipients().get(i));
        }
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        // 3) create MimeBodyPart object and set your message text
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();

        // 4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to
        // this object
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart1.setContent(request.getContent(),
                EmailConstants.TYPE_HTML);
        message.setSubject(request.getSubject());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
        // 6) set the multiplart object to the message object
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // 7) send message
        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I have tried all the variations I could find out here in StackOverflow but nothing helped. Tried [MkYong.com Java Mail Example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) but same error.

Also changed the `PORT` to `465` and added these statements in properties but still the same issue.

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", PORT);
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

Interestingly, I am using the same code to send emails from my `corp-account` and it works just fine. Just provided corp host name and port as 25 and it is working.

Am trying to deploy this to AWS where corp account does not work so need to migrate to Gmail.

Am using `Java 8` and `Mail API` is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Am trying to ping at `smtp.gmail.com` which is connecting but when I do **`telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`** it keeps on trying but doesn't connect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which tutorial did you use?

Comment: if even telnet isn't working, it could be that your corporate network blocks this host, which is quite often case.

Comment: You're using a version old version of JavaMail, [please upgrade](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  The Gmail instructions are in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail), as are [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  As mentioned above, you probably have a firewall blocking your access.  The JavaMail FAQ has [information about that as well](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
public class AppConfig {
        @Bean
        public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
            log.info("Init mail sender bean");
            JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
            mailSender.setPort(587);
            mailSender.setUsername("Username");
            mailSender.setPassword("Password");

            Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            return mailSender;
        }
}
public class EmailSender {
..
      @Autowired
      public JavaMailSender emailSender;

      public void send(String from, String to, String subject, String body, boolean html) {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = createMimeMessage(subject);
            getMimeMessageHelper(from, to, subject, body, html, message, false);
            emailSender.send(message);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```